# Python - how to convert string 2020-07-28T00:00:00.000Z to date 2020-07-28

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to compare the 2 dates and the dates comes like below from a microservice:

```
[{"visitId": 1, "userId": 1, "branchId": 1, "date": "2020-07-28T00:00:00.000Z"},{"visitId": 2,"userId": 1,"branchId": 2,"date": "2020-07-28T00:00:00.000Z"}]
```

How to parse the dates and compare they are equal.

I tried the below code and it gives me value error:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.fromisoformat(dt)

ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2020-07-28T00:00:00.000Z'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dateutil` library. It's a little more flexible

```
In [73]: a
Out[73]:
[{'visitId': 1,
  'userId': 1,
  'branchId': 1,
  'date': '2020-07-28T00:00:00.000Z'},
 {'visitId': 2,
  'userId': 1,
  'branchId': 2,
  'date': '2020-07-28T00:00:00.000Z'}]

In [75]: b = []

In [76]: for i in a:
    ...:     b.append(dateutil.parser.parse(i["date"]))
    ...:

In [77]: b
Out[77]:
[datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 28, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 28, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import datetime

data = [
    {"visitId": 1, "userId": 1, "branchId": 1, "date": "2020-07-28T00:00:00.000Z"},
    {"visitId": 2, "userId": 1, "branchId": 2, "date": "2020-07-28T00:00:00.000Z"},
]


d1 = datetime.strptime(data[0]["date"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
d2 = datetime.strptime(data[1]["date"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

`d1` and `d2` are datetime objects, now you can compare them using Comparison operators.